# MySQL: SELECT 2 tables with different columns name and amount

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need help.
I have 2 tables.

> Table 1 with 4 column (email, firstname, lastname, status)
>
> Table 2 with 1 column (address)

And I want to query 2 tables with the result like this:

> New Table with 5 column (email, firstname, lastname, status, address)

I already tried with JOIN statement like this

```
SELECT email, firstname, lastname, status FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (0)
```

The result will be just 4 columns from table1.

And if I use RIGHT JOIN, the result will be the same 4 columns from table1, buat all NULL values.

And with INNER JOIN, the result 4 columns from table1 and with none values.

And then I use UNION like this

```
SELECT email, firstname, lastname, status FROM table1
UNION
SELECT address, '', '', '' FROM table2
```

The result will be same as LEFT JOIN RESULT.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `ON (0)` means that no rows match the join condition (0 is false), you need to provide an expression that's true for the corresponding rows in the two tables. How is mysql supposed to know which rows of the two tables should be joined together?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a relationship between the two tables i don't understand the need of making two separate tables. I suggest you to make a relation between the tables

an example would be

```
 table1(email, firstname, lastname, addressID), table2(addressID,Address)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have these two tables, you can do it like babooney said or you can make one more table that will have two foreign keys, one from table1 an another from table2.

example: `table3(id, id_table1, id_table2)`